# how to restart a Mon in a Ceph cluster

Tags: ceph

I am running a Ceph Cluster (pacific) consisting of 3 nodes. I have 3 Monitor Daemons started (one on each node).

Just for some test I wanted to remove node3 out of the list of monitors with the command

```
sudo ceph mon remove node3
```

The mon disappeared  in the Dashboard and also when I call ceph status command:

```
$ sudo ceph status
  cluster:
    id:     xxxxx-yyyyy-zzzzzzz
    health: HEALTH_WARN
            1 failed cephadm daemon(s)
 
  services:
    mon: 2 daemons, quorum node1,node2 (age 53m)
    mgr: node1.gafnwm(active, since 102m), standbys: node2.jppwxo
    osd: 3 osds: 3 up (since 15m), 3 in (since 96m)
```

But now I found no way to restart or add the monitor again into my cluster. I tried:

```
$ sudo ceph orch daemon add mon node3:10.0.0.4
Error EINVAL: name mon.node3 already in use
```

What does this mean? Why is the name `mon.node3` already in use even if I can't see it?

Comment: If you run `cephadm ls` on that node you will see the previous daemon. Remove it with `cephadm rm-daemon --name mon.<YOUR_MON>`. If that worked you'll most likely be able to redeploy the mon again.

Comment: The mon was listed in the 'cephadm ls' resultlist. I removed it with `sudo cephadm rm-daemon --name mon.node3 --fsid xxxx-yyyy-zzz --force` and the daemon disapeard in the `cephadm ls`. In the web dashboard it is still listed (strange) and still I am not able to add it. I got the same error message `Error EINVAL: name mon.node3 already in use`

Comment: I tried a reboot of the node and than the mon disappeared also in the web dashboard and now I was able to add the mon again ! Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Sometimes cephadm needs some time to update its information, most operations are delayed, so it could also have worked just with some waiting instead of reboot, but great that it worked that way, too.

Comment: I suppose you could speed up the update if you restart mgr daemon. Or I've just been lucky.